# What do I have to include on a C program to use POSIX system calls?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, system-calls, minix

I'm learning about operating systems on The MINIX Book (Tanembaum), and one of the exercises I went through is to build a VERY simple shell.

For this, the book provides this piece of code:

```
#define TRUE 1

while (TRUE) {
   type_prompt();
   read_command(command, parameters);

   if (fork() != 0) {
      waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
   } else {
      execve(command, parameters, 0);
   }
}
```

This is not the entire C program (obviously) and I need to declare some variables and write some functions by my own. But `fork()`, for example, is a system call (as said in the book, it should be POSIX compatible).

What `#include` directives my program should have to use them, assuming I am compiling this program on MINIX already (and all other functions that I wrote are in this same .c file)? How does it work to use Linux system calls on C programs?

Thanks!

Comment: `man <command-or-function>` is a very important command, used like for example `man fork`.

Comment: As Joachim mentioned, you need to read the docs - different APIs need different headers.  Also you may need to define "feature macros" that indicate to the system which specific set of APIs you want activated.  See `man feature_test_macros`.  You'd probably be OK to start with `-D_GNU_SOURCE`, as that includes pretty much everything.

Comment: The master to the man-pages coming with Linux is here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages The one for `fork()` is here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html The POSIX reference:  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html

Comment: Also study the source code of simple free software shells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A google search of `man fork` will show the linux man page and it indicates that it needs:

```
#include <unistd.h>
```